# Push an element into a stack in an array with multiple stack pushes the element in all the stacks

Tags: java, arrays, stack

got a small problem when i am trying to push an element(Card) into a stack. 
I got an array containing 4 stacks, representing 4 piles of cards.  But when i try to push the card into one of the stacks, it pushes in all of them instead. I bet there is just some stupid mistake in there, but my brain is not very alive atm..

Anyway the code:

```
stacks = new CardStack[4];   //array with 4 slots


   // Creating 4 stacks and placing each in one slot in the array
for (int i =0; i<4; i++){    
        CardStack<Card> stack = new CardStack<Card>(i+1);
        stacks[i] = stack;
    }
```

if i try to

```
stacks[0].push(currentCard);
```

it seems to be pushing the card into all of the stacks, and not just the stack at index 0 in the stacks array.

Comment: Show code for CardStack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have an array or `List` field inside `CardStack` to store the elements that will behave as a stack structure. Make sure this field is not `static`, otherwise it will be bound to the class, and all instances of the class will share the same array, `List` or whatever object it is.

More info:

- [Why are static variables considered evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7026507/1065197)